# autotools: pass constant from configure.ac to python script

Tags: python, autotools, automake

I want to pass a constant in a C preprocessor style but with a Python script.

This constant is already declared with `AC_DEFINE` in my `configure.ac` file and used in my C program, and now I need to pass it to a Python script too.

I tried with a custom target in my `Makefile.am` with a `sed` call to preprocess a specific symbol in my Python script, but it seems dirty-coding to me.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `config.py.in` with some contents like `MYVAR = '''@MYVAR@'''` and add it to `AC_CONFIG_FILES` in your `configure.ac`. You can then import `config` in your other Python scripts.

This fulfills much the same function as `config.h` does for C programs.